# How can I change the decimal separator from "." to "," only for a specific cell using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am absolutly new in Excel and I have the following problem multiplying 2 values.

I will try to explain you my situation.

Into a sheet named **currenciesInfo** I have that each row is a currency and the **P** coulmn contains the value in € of this currency.

I am retrieving the content of this **currenciesInfo** sheet connecting Excel to an API.

The retrieved value is something like **728.454911165** and it is formatted as a **number**.

Then into another sheet named **ETH** I retrieve the € value of a specific currency by this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("CurrenciesInfo!"&ADDRESS(MATCH("ETH";CurrenciesInfo!C:C;0);16))
```

and putting this value into the **K6** cell of this **ETH** sheet

Ok, now in this **ETH** sheet I have another field named **K2** field containing a number like **0,0783272400**

The problem is that when I try to multiply the **K6** and the **K2** cell by this simple formula:

```
=K3*K6
```

I obtain a non sense value like: **57.057.862.655,9996000000**

I think that the problem is related to the fact that into the **CurrenciesInfo** sheet I am retrieving this value **728.454911165** that use the **.** symbol as decimal separator while into the other sheet the decimal separator is **,**.

Infact if into the **CurrenciesInfo** sheet I manually change the **.** symbol with the **,** symbol. The calculation is done correctly and this formula:

```
=K3*K6
```

get me the correct result that is **57,0578626560**

So, how can I handle this situation? The problem is that the values into the **CurrenciesInfo** sheet are automatically retrieved using an API that provide me the data only in this format.

Exist a way to do something like this?

1) Into the **CurrenciesInfo** sheet the value is retrieved by the API in this format **728.454911165** having the **.** as decimal separator.

2) When into the **ETH** sheet I retrieve this value using this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("CurrenciesInfo!"&ADDRESS(MATCH("ETH";CurrenciesInfo!C:C;0);16))
```

I change in some way the **.** symbol with the **,** symbol (so I have the expected value with the **,** in the **K6** cell and the multiplication should work fine)

Can I do something like this?

Comment: I know it is not what you are asking for but `INDIRECT` can be avoided in above case by using a formula like `=INDEX(CurrenciesInfo!P:P;MATCH("ETH";CurrenciesInfo!C:C;0))`. INDIRECT is volatile function and its extensive usage may slow down the workbook.

Comment: Decimal separator and thousands separator are at system level. However, you can override them in Excel by editing `File>>Options>>Advanced>>Use System Separator` but I would not recommend that and those you cannot manipulate at sheet level or cell level.

Answer (score 1):

@[shrivallabha.redij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959480/how-can-i-change-the-decimal-separator-from-to-only-for-a-specific-cell#comment82888379_47959480) has explained that the separator is either at the operating system or application level - what you ask is not possible. However the result `57,0578626560` can be achieved with your settings if you include division by 10^9 in your currency calculation:

```
 =K3*K6/10^9
```

You should also format the result as General to avoid lots of full stops in the answer (and heed @[shrivallabha.redij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8759927/shrivallabha-redij) advice regarding the volatile INDIRECT if your sheet shows any signs of being slow to update).

And, IMO, it would have been better to ask this and your previous question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) rather than here.